# get a specific property for a domain in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i'm making a tables cleaning service that takes the table name and the date field as arguments , here is the service code :

```
def cleanTables(tableName , dateField) {
    def comparisonDate
    def numOfRecordsDeleted
    use (TimeCategory){
        comparisonDate=new Date() -1.year
        }
    numOfRecordsDeleted=tableName.where { dateField <=comparisonDate }.deleteAll()
    log.info("deleted : " +numOfRecordsDeleted)
}
```

i'm successfully passing to this service the `table name` but i can't pass the `date field` , so how to get a specific property from a domain for example a domain named `Payments` got a property `dateCreated` , so i pass to my service `Payments` and `dateCreated`.

Comment: If you want to use this function to specific domain classes why don't you create helper domain class, where you can store pairs: unique tableName and relevant dateField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *where queries* you have access to *criteria query* methods such as `eq()`, or in this case, `le()`. Those methods take the *name* of the property as an argument, which is what you need. I tweaked the code a bit because you're actually interacting with domain classes, not tables. Small distinction, until you start working with HQL.

```
def cleanDomainClass(String domainClassName, String dateField) {
    def domainClass = Class.forName("some.package.$domainClassName")
    def comparisonDate = use (TimeCategory) { new Date() -1.year }
    def numOfRecordsDeleted = domainClass.where { le(dateField, comparisonDate) }.deleteAll()

    log.info("deleted : $numOfRecordsDeleted")
}
```